# Invert Delete Only Faces Op

Tags: mesh, topology

I have a grid of interconnected vertices and want to create faces out of them.

[image]

This is exactly opposite of selecting the faces and invoking X followed by 'Only Faces'.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the vertices.
2. Hit <kbd>F</kbd> for fill.

[image]

Comment: Will it? It didn't when I tested it. I also disabled F2 addon to see if it works by default. Seems to work.

Comment: I had tried F but my normals had some issues. Thanks for the demo.

Comment: Nevermind, that issue only happens without adjacent faces.